# Create line between two entities - RealityKit Skeleton

Tags: swift, realitykit

I currently work on a body tracking app with RealityKit and draw circles at all the joints. I would now like to connect the joints with lines to get a proper skeleton.

How can I draw a line from a starting vector to an ending vector?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is by creating a rectangle line, basically, compute the distance between two entities and draw the line.

```
// size is equal to the distance between two entities
let rectangle = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(width: 0.003, height: 0.003, depth: size), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: UIColor(.blue), isMetallic: false)])
    
// middle point of two points             
let middlePoint : simd_float3 = simd_float3((startPoint.x + endPoint.x)/2, (startPoint.y + endPoint.y)/2, (startPoint.z + endPoint.z)/2)
        
let lineAnchor = AnchorEntity()
lineAnchor.position = middlePoint
lineAnchor.look(at: startPoint!, from: middlePoint, relativeTo: nil)
lineAnchor.addChild(rectangle)
arView.scene.addAnchor(lineAnchor)
```

Not sure if this is what you want. I use the same code for the measurement app I'm creating.